# Is there a way to communicate between background thread and current viewcontroller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

There are several ViewControllers in my storyboard, and there is a background thread which is used to receive message from a server, the background thread and the ViewControllers are in different classes.

According to message received, i want to transport the message to a specified ViewController, i used to use Handler to do this thing in Android, but how to do this in swift?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: use  Observers  to efficiently communicate with View Controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends, you have plenty of options. How did you manage your connection?

1. you can use delegation (paying attention to make the delegate call
   on the main thread), if you need 1.1 communication
2. you can use `NSNoticationCenter` and register your view controllers to specific notifications that you'll generate based on the server answer, (paying attention to post them on the main thread). Good if you need 1.* communication
3. you can even use `GCD` blocks (paying attention to call them on the main thread)

The suggestion to make the calls on the main thread is pretty general and it depends on your requirements, but mostly correct if need to update your UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use  Foundation.NSNotification

Answer (score 0):

U can achieve this using `Notification`.

In your background thread once  you receive  message from server , post your message like this

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
     })
```

and register the `Notification Observer` on your each `ViewController` class

like this

```
class A:UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "UpdateValues", name: "NotificationIdentifier", object: nil) 
   }

  func UpdateValues(){   
      // put your code 
  }

}
```